# How to align the label text with prefix icon in a outlined text form field box in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In the below image, the label text is aligned with the input field data.
How to align the label text with the prefix icon?

[image]

Below is the alignment i want!How to get this using TEXTFORMFIELD?

[image]

Comment: this link can help,same question as you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906419/flutter-textfield-labeltext-center

Comment: No it didnt,thank you for trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look

```
TextFormField(
                  style:
                  TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0, color: Colors.black),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefix: Icon(Icons.email, size: 20,),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: "Email",
                  )
              ),
```

output:
[image]

Comment: I want  to align the label text straight above with the icon.

Comment: @EAvijay can you post the image what do you want?

Comment: @EAvijay look at the solution.

Comment: @JahidulIslam this is good but I want this alignment with text form field not textfield ,if i use this method. Will it work for textform field?

Comment: @EAvijay yeah this is work for textformfield as well as textfield.

Comment: It is not working for textformfield i tried

Comment: i tried with textform field and gave same result

Comment: you just replace TextField with TextFormField

Comment: I want to add validator too

Comment: yes it got fixed .Thank you for help Jahidul Islam. But Only when entering the input data ,icon is visible,when no data is entered in text filed[intially ].,the icon is not visible.When clicked in the field , the icon pops up,So it would be nice,if i have the icon even before clicking into the text input field.

Comment: @JahidulIslam how can i center the prefix its like the prefix is slightly above whatever i am typing in my TextFormField

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo wrap icon with `center` widget

Comment: @JahidulIslam wrapping icon with Center takes the icon to the center horizontal of the TextFormField and i can't type anymore